# loading data from webservice in onresume

Tags: android

I am calling web service in onresume() to get the data from the server.. the problem is if user minimises and opens the app again it will call the web service to get the data. I d'not want to load the data again on such condition . what is the best way to load data in that case.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
lAttendence= getAttendence ('goku' ,'20/mar/2016' ,'21/mar/2016');
EtAtendence.setText(lAttendence)
    super.onResume();
}   




public String getAttendence(String pStuid, String pFromdate, String pTodate){
     final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://adad.org/attendenceDetail";
        final String METHOD_NAME = "attendenceDetail";
        final String NAMESPACE = "http://xxxx.org/";
        final String URL = "http://xxxxx.in/service.asmx";


        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);           
        request.addProperty("pStuID", pStuid);
        request.addProperty("pFromDate",pFromdate );
        request.addProperty("pTodate",pTodate );
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet = true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
 String result="";
        HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        try {
         ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            Object responses = envelope.getResponse();
            result=responses.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

return result;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific and show some code.

Comment: Look into the Loader pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a singleton that save the information, or use SharedPreferences and save the information there. In my case i'm using a singleton, but i read that SharedPreferences is a better practice.
Singleton is an object with only one instance inside of it, a private constructor and a getInstance methos that returns the inner instance. Use atributes to save the information.
Example:

```
piblie class singleton{
private String oneString;
private singleton instance;
private singleton(){}
public static initialize(){instance=new singleton();}
public static singleton getInstance(){ return instance;}
public void setString(String s){ oneString=s;}
public String getString(){return oneString;}
}
```

And you should use a class tath extens from Application, an put this on the onCreate():

```
singleton.initialize()
```

For SharedPreferences: http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

**EDIT:** If ti's only for a String, you should use SharedPreferences
Something like this:

```
    String AppName="your_app_name";
    String theString="";
    SharedPreferences shared=getSharedPreferences(AppName, 0);
    if(!shared.contains("your_saved_thing_name"))
    {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor =shared.edit();
        editor.putString("your_saved_thing_name",webserviceCall());
        editor.commit();
    }
    theString=shared.getInt("your_saved_thing_name", webserviceCall());
```

Comment: If it is an array of objects what we can do?... thank u for your answer

Comment: I think you can use SharedPreferences too, but i never do that. I use singletons for the arrays, instead of the oneString in the example you can use whatever you want and more than one if you want